# mysql median value per month

Tags: mysql, median

I am doing some queries from a database to make graphs, and a graph that may be needed is the median of a set of values per month. I know how to get the median of the whole set of our data, but for some reason I can't get GROUP BY MONTH(..) to separate the months so it returns the median per month.

Here is the data that I have and I'd like for every month to get the median value for each month regardless of build type.

```
'Development', 1013.0164, 'June'
'Development', 1170.8999, 'July'
'Development', 671.2837, 'August'
'Flash Assets', 2961.3832, 'June'
'Flash Assets', 6662.2335, 'July'
'Flash Assets', 3902.5000, 'August'
'Release', 54.5499, 'June'
'Release', 62.4832, 'July'
'Release', 398.8500, 'August'
'Repackage', 1360.0834, 'June'
'Repackage', 6286.8505, 'July'
'Repackage', 1274.7833, 'August'
'Component', 16378.0161, 'June'
'Component', 6063.5482, 'July'
'Component', 23663.2496, 'August'
'Source Diff', 1503.8834, 'June'
'Source Diff', 1051.4500, 'July'
'Source Diff', 73.7002, 'August'
```

I'd like to end up with this,

```
June, XXXX
July, XXXX
August, XXXX
```

Thanks.

**EDIT: Current Query**

This is the query that I am using right now to get the overall median, I am not sure how to translate this to getting it per month.

```
 SELECT t.Data AS 'Median' FROM
 (SELECT CEIL(COUNT(*)/2.0) as 'Middle', s.Data as 'Data' FROM
 (SELECT bt.name as 'Labels', 
 SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(bs.eventtime, b.submittime))/60.0) 
 AS 'Data', MONTHNAME(b.submittime) FROM builds b 
 JOIN buildstatuses bs ON bs.buildid = b.id 
 JOIN buildtypes bt ON bt.id = b.buildtype 
 WHERE MONTH(b.submittime) BETWEEN MONTH(CURDATE())-2 AND MONTH(CURDATE()) 
 AND bs.status LIKE 'Started HANDLER' 
 GROUP BY b.buildtype, MONTH(b.submittime) ORDER BY 'Data' ) s )t;
```

Comment: the last column is a string that holds the date. I am just using the `MONTHNAME()` function here to display the name

Comment: How do you get the median, AFAIK MySQL doesn't offer an aggregate function for this (as implied by your use of GROUP BY)?

Comment: Right now I am about to get the median of the whole data set by using a nested select. What I would really like is the median of data per month. Ill edit above and post the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your value is always in float ... you can try this --

assume `Data` is the value column

```
select mth,
substring_index
(
  substring_index
  (
    group_concat(Data order by Data), ',', 
    count(*)/2+1
  ), 
  ',', -1
)
from your_tables
group by mth;
```

- `group_concat` will sort the values for month in ascending order
- then use of first `substring_index` will return from first value to middle value +1 more position
- then next `substring_index` will help you to ge tthe right most value (which is the median)

Comment: group_concat_max_len is usually set to 1024, so your data will be truncated at length 1024.  This example only works on very small data sets.

Comment: you can always set a bigger for group_concat_max_len

Answer (score 1):

Peolple [at the mysql's aggregate functions discussion page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) ends up with temporary tables. Search for "median" there.

Comment: this shows how to get the median yes, but what I am looking for is the Median per month.

Comment: Include group by month in temp table creation and you'll have the medain per month.